# Difference between restarting tomcat via shell script and via command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat

I want to restart Tomcat

I have made a shell script(name a.sh)

a.sh Contents

```
/bin/sh /tomcatdirectroy/bin/shutdown.sh
/bin/sleep 120
/bin/sh /tomcatdirectroy/bin/startup.sh
```

When I excute a.sh (/bin/sh a.sh), I get a Tomcat memory leak error....

This error doesn't occur when I start the scripts from the commandline:

```
/bin/sh /tomcatdirectroy/bin/shutdown.sh
/bin/sleep 120
/bin/sh /tomcatdirectroy/bin/startup.sh
```

and now Tomcat runs in normal operation without memory leak.

why..?

What is the difference between calling the start and stop scripts using
an other shell script calling them from the command line ?

a.sh excute (catalina.out Contents)

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.832 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.832 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.833 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.833 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.833 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.834 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.834 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-11] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.835 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wiki] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-12] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.835 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.atlassian.confluence.concurrent.ThreadLocalMap] (value [com.atlassian.confluence.concurrent.ThreadLocalMap@778ef6c9]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.836 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@3e57e58d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.836 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@11a17319]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.836 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@f2747fb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.837 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@45a124cf]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.837 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@44dbca7b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.837 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@5e785042]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.837 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@6bd5dce9]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.837 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@4dac55b5]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionContext@279e1a00]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.838 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1] (value [org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1@396e5a12]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@3d0c849a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.839 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [wiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime$1] (value [net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime$1@216a3939]) and a value of type [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] (value [java.text.SimpleDateFormat@6f64295a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.845 INFO [Thread-53] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
26-Feb-2017 00:39:49.943 INFO [Thread-53] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
```

Comment: Can you post actual error you get when you execute `a.sh`?

Comment: I think your question is why there is /bin/sh of 2 shell scripts inside a single script. Its basically Isolation & reuse of functionality. You have 2 separate scripts shutdown.sh and startup.sh which you can use separately .  You can also combine them into a single script for a complete restart.. More over you are starting a subshell inside a shell in given a.sh

Comment: Contact Atlassian support for the memory leak.